# Not getting any idea about the workflow of managing an android device from another device using an pre installed android in both devices

Tags: android, enterprise, mdm

I have a new project at hand where I need to make two android applications
1)***Main Controller application*** (be installed in one device say its name be X)
2)***Sub Child application*** (be installed in devices that need to be controlled by X )

So I  want to get an idea/picture about how one android device like (2) can be managed fully(i.e. blocking applications or making them accessible for some interval / block calls / track location of user ) from another device like (1). So far I searched Google ,asked my seniors about the same but none was able to help me out.Found many scattered info (like need enterprise app to do this i.e use android management API or Device admin ) but not being able to get any clear idea about the work flow.

**Thus now this the last place I can think of for helping me out with this work flow.**

### [Reference](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qustodio.qustodioapp)

**Update:** Based on what @Fred said i.e. to use android management API (also based on the answers that he posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49689440/10683839)) could we somehow have own custom web server and manage the interactions that EMM console does with all the child apps through our own API's(the same API's which we would call from the parent app.) ???
***In other words instead of controlling form the EMM console, I would like to control those child application from another parent android application.***

Comment: You could try using the [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/).

Comment: Hi @Fred Tried android management API.Created enterprise, enrollment token using policy. Then added to my one of android oreo device. But when i try to list devices its showing empty. I am using sample code provided in here -> https://developers.google.com/android/management/sample-app

Answer (score 0):

By FCM or Socket programming you can easily communicate with other app. Suppose 2nd app receive a call then 2nd app call a api of server about the information, then server knock 1st app by fcm or socket, then 1st app make a decision and submit the decision to server by API, And finally server submit the decision to 2nd app by FCM or socket.

Comment: What abut disabling access of  other application in child device? Say  facebook or whatsapp

Comment: You have to work on onApplication launch event of other app. May need administrator permission.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [Flyve MDM](https://github.com/flyve-mdm) which is an open source mobile device management solution including both agent app and web panel for management.