# Does Android management API support custom DPC apps?

Tags: android, kiosk-mode, android-management-api, cosu, android-enterprise

> https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/build-dpc
>
> Caution: Android Enterprise is no longer accepting new registrations
>   for custom device policy controllers (DPCs). Learn more.

Hi @Fred,

I found this above information from the mentioned path.
I have some questions regarding the above conversation.

1. If we use Android management API to develop EMM, we don't need to implement Custom DPC app?
2. Whether we can register a account in EMM community with Custom DPC app?
3. Is it possible to use a custom DPC app with Android management API?

Reference: [How does designing custom android DPC app relate to Android management API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49688616/how-does-designing-custom-android-dpc-app-relate-to-android-management-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **old way** of managing Android devices is no longer available for new deployments. You must now use the **new way**, which means using the [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/) and not using a custom DPC (it's not possible to use a custom DPC with the Android Management API.

Here is the copy of my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49688616/how-does-designing-custom-android-dpc-app-relate-to-android-management-api/49689440#49689440) which explains the two ways for managing Android devices:

> There are two distinct ways of managing Android devices:
>
> The **new way**: the [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/). It is the way recommended by Google and it's significantly simpler than the old way, you don't need to call other APIs or to create a custom DPC. If your use case is not addressed by this API you can [send feedback](https://developers.google.com/android/management/feedback) to Google so they can add the missing features.
>
> The **old way**: using custom DPC. For that you need to:
>
> - [create a custom DPC](https://developers.google.com/android/work/dpc/build-dpc),
> - register your custom DPC with Google by [joining the EMM Community](https://developers.google.com/android/work/register) (this is how you get the afw#DPC_NAME),
> - use the [Google Play EMM API](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/) to install apps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. And one more information i need to know, once we finish the EMM Development whether we need to get approval from Google before deploy the EMM console?

Comment: If you don't plan to manage more than 1000 devices simultaneously you can use the Android Management API without any approval. If you plan to go beyond 1000 devices you need to [join the EMM community](https://developers.google.com/android/management/join), and depending on your use case you may be required to validate a [set of features](https://developers.google.com/android/work/release-solution#3_develop_your_solution).

Comment: If I ask permission they are suggesting me to see Android management API. But already I'm developing the features using Android management API.
So I want to know, Do I need to give any other information